# Objective Sharpie Fails to generate binding

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a simple binding to an enterprise library using Objective Sharpie.
It keeps failing with the following message:

> Cannot be negative.
>   Parameter name: length
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Cannot be negative.
>   Parameter name: length
>     at System.String.Substring (Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Sharpie.ObjC.ObjCExtensions.ToGetAccessorSelectorFromSetAccessor (System.String selector) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Sharpie.ObjC.CodeDomMassager.MassageMethod (Sharpie.CodeDom.TypeDeclaration type, Sharpie.CodeDom.MethodDeclaration method) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Sharpie.ObjC.CodeDomMassager.MassageTypeMembers[MethodDeclaration] (Sharpie.CodeDom.TypeDeclaration type, System.Action`2 massager) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>     at Sharpie.ObjC.CodeDomMassager.MassageType (Sharpie.CodeDom.TypeDeclaration type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>     at Sharpie.ObjC.CodeDomMassager.MassageAll () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>     at Sharpie.ObjC.Parser.Parse (System.IO.TextWriter sexpWriter, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 stderrLines) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Sharpie.Mac.MainWindowController+c_*AnonStorey3.<>m*_B (System.Object o) [0x00000] in :0

From other answers I found that there might be a problem with accessors but I don't find

> (void)get

or

> (void)set

in my code. Help!

Comment: We cannot help without seeing the header files. Such issues are better filed as bug reports @ http://bugzilla.xamarin.com where you can attach (privately if needed) the header files.

Comment: I did, and since then nothing happened. How can I tell it's even in a queue?

Comment: Did you try using latest sharpie v3.4.0?